# MVC function is not giving a result

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, software-design

Recently im trying to do a model view controller for my software engneering course project. My device model functions are all working fine except for the function listallmydevices() idk whats going on and no errors are visible.

Note i've changed my function to another list function from another class and its working fine except for the device

```html
<html>
        
<head>
    <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
</head>
    
  <style>
.dropdown-submenu 
      {
    position: relative;
     }

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu 
{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>
    
   

<form action="../prototype/mvc/DeviceController.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    
<label for="id">ID:</label>
<input type="text" name="ID" >
 <br><br>
                                                                             
<label for="username">Device Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="un" name="Name">
<br><br>
    
<label for="lastname">Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="Date">
<br><br>
    
<label for="fs">Amount:</label>
<input type="text"  name="Amount">
<br><br> 
    
<label for="ls">Price:</label>
<input type="text" name="Price">
<br><br>
    
<label for="mail">Brand:</label>
<input type="mail" name="Brand">
<br><br> 
    
<label for="password">MarketingToolsID:</label>
<input type="password" name="MTID">
<br><br> 
    
<label for="password">Tochange: </label>
<input type="password" name="edit">
<br><br>

    <label for="password">Tochange: </label>
    <select name="Cateogry">
    
    <option>Price </option>
    <option>Amount </option>
    <option> Name</option>
    <option> </option>
    <option> </option>
    
    
    
    </select>
    <br>
    
        <input type="submit" name="DELETEDEVICE" value="DELETE DEVICE">
        <input type="submit" name="ADDDEVICE" value="ADD DEVICE" >
        <input type="submit" name="VIEWALLDEVICES" value="VIEW ALL DEVICES" >
        <input type="submit" name="EDITDEVICE" value="Edit  DEVICES" >
        

    
    </form>



-->
```

```
public static function listalldevices()
{
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bioster");

 $sql="Select * from device order by DeviceID";

 $devicequery= mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

 $i=0;
 $result;

 while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($devicequery))
 {
     $devobj=new device($row["DeviceID"]);

     $result[$i]=$devobj;

     $i++;
 }
 return $result;


}
```

Device controller

```
if(isset($_POST['VIEWALLDEVICES']))
 {

    $array= Device::listalldevices();

    echo "All devices";

    for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
    {

        echo $array[$i]->DeviceID;
        echo $array[$i]->Name;
        echo $array[$i]->Date;
        echo $array[$i]->Amount;
        echo $array[$i]->Price;
        echo $array[$i]->Brand;
    }



} //check this not wotking
```

Comment: Please do not write your mysql credentials even if they are wrong.